# Rewriting the laws

Tags: discussion

Is it possible for us to take a vote or take suggestions from the community to make this SE more user friendly?

For example, new users have a bit of a hard time adjusting to the well maintained uniform here. Even though all the moderators do a great job, i think it will be a help for them and all the users to set the bar a bit low. If laws and regulations are a bit more flexible it would be nice.

Now i do not mean changing the essentials, what i mean is a flexible set of rules. This SE can attract a lot of people if it becomes a bit more like Reddit. But we can't have the same going on because we are a Q&A site, But some changes are possible and necessary.

Namo Buddhaya!

Comment: Yes it's possible to take suggestions and to discuss and vote on the suggestion -- that's what Meta is for. We've had (only) 3 questions closed in the last 30 days: which doesn't suggest to me that we're excessively strict? And the [Moderation policy for questions](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) is already more permissive than on other SE sites: so I don't see a general/systemic problem with being inflexible, but maybe you'd like to point one out? We can also use Meta to discuss specific posts.

Comment: Yes, i agree it is more free here. Let me wait and add such occasions once i see them. I think it would be easier than going through questions. Thanks Chris.